# ¿Como agregar un Objeto dentro de otro Objeto?

Tags: javascript, json, objeto

Ando creando una grafica Candlestick para poder visualizar el movimiento de criptomonedas, para darle la informacion debo pasarla en formato de objeto

Ejemplo

```
[
{"x": "12 de enero", "o": 123, "h": 125, "l": 120, "c": 120},
{"x": "13 de enero", "o": 123, "h": 125, "l": 120, "c": 120},
{"x": "14 de enero", "o": 123, "h": 125, "l": 120, "c": 120}]
```

Ahora, estoy obteniendo los datos reales y estoy buscando como hacer lo siguiente

```js
let CompleteOBJData = [] //<- Este sera el objeto con el que le dare todos los datos a Chart.js

for(let i= 0; i< 10; i++){

    //Obtengo los datos y los guardo en un OBJ local

    locaobj = [{"x":"12 de enero", "o": 123, "h": 125, "l":102, "c":102}]

    //Quiero hacer que localobj se agrege a CompleteOBJData sin que se elimine la informacion que ya existe

}
```

Comment: sería `CompleteOBJData.push(locaobj)` pero vas a agregar 10 veces lo mismo.

Comment: Tenes unas diferencias teóricas que tal vez te confundan. CompleteOBJData no es un objeto, es un array de objetos. Al ser un array, podrias insertarle un elemento con el método ``.push()``. El tema es que ``locaobj`` tambien es un array. Ese si deberia ser un objeto (solo tenes que sacarle [ y ]). Ahora si, deberias hacer ``CompleteObjData.push(locaobj)``, y eso agregaria el objeto ``locaobj`` al final del array ``CompleteObjData``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let CompleteOBJData = []; //<- Este sera el objeto con el que le dare todos los datos a Chart.js
for(let i= 0; i< 10; i++){
    locaobj = [{"x":"12 de enero", "o": 123, "h": 125, "l":102, "c":102}];
    CompleteOBJData.push(locaobj); // Usar push para agregar los objetos al arreglo deseado.
}

console.log(CompleteOBJData);
```

Puedes leer mas sobre push [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)